# Generating Sencha Touch 2 app nullpointer error

Tags: linux, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to generate a new app using the following:

```
root@li184-76:/var/www/touch-2.3.1# sencha generate app NewApp ../newapp
```

However, I get the following:

```
    Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.4
    [INF] Workspace does not have framework touch at /var/www ... copying
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.sencha.util.Version.<init>(Version.java:36)
     at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$WorkspaceCommand.getParameters(GeneratorCommands.java:130)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:23)
     at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$WorkspaceCommand.execute(GeneratorCommands.java:89)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractCommand.java:124)
     at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$AppCommand.generateWorkspace(GeneratorCommands.java:397)
     at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$AppCommand.execute(GeneratorCommands.java:240)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:148)
```

The confusing thing is I already have previously generated apps. I don't know why my attempts to create new ones are failing.

**NOTE:**

I tried upgrading Sencha but it does seems to have the desire effect as the following shows:

```
root@li184-76:/var/www/touch-2.3.1# sencha upgrade
Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
[INF] Determining the latest version of Sencha Cmd
[INF] The latest version of Sencha Cmd is 4.0.2.67
[INF] Sencha Cmd 4.0.2.67 is already installed
```

**UPDATE:**

I attempted to generate the app from outside the TOUCH folder but I get a weird error about SampleApp already existing. I have nothing called SampleApp in the target directory.
The data is as follows:

```
root@li184-76:/var/www# sencha -sdk /var/www/touch-2.3.1/ generate app MyApp /var/www/myapp
Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
[ERR] Path /var/www/myapp is already a configured application named : SampleApp
[ERR] Path /var/www/myapp is already configured for application SampleApp
root@li184-76:/var/www#
```

Comment: did you try sencha upgrade ?

Comment: I updated my question to indicate results to my upgrade attempt.

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.10.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With thanks to arthurakay and Anand Gupta for your input and attempts to help, I eventually figured out the problem.

What had happened was at some point I corrupted my /var/www directory by attempting to generate a sencha app in the same, i:e /var/www, directory. That was the mistake that was causing all the havoc.

Luckily, I happened to list all the hidden files and found a **.sencha** folder which is why it kept complaining about **SampleApp** as described in the update section of my question.

Once I removed the .sencha folder and other related data, things moved beyond this to other challenges.

Thanks again for all your input.

Comment: The same exact thing happened to me. Thanks for the tip on the hidden .sencha directory!

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace you posted doesn't seem to have much info... but I notice that your command

```
sencha generate app NewApp ../newapp
```

doesn't include the *-sdk* flag. If you run your command from *inside* a Sencha Touch folder then you wouldn't need the *-sdk* flag... but if you're anywhere else on the filesystem you need to tell Sencha Cmd which SDK to use.

Comment: I was executing the sencha generate command within the TOUCH folder extracted from sencha-touch-2.3.1a-gpl.zip. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: I also notice in your stack traces that it says Cmd 4.0.2.67 is installed... yet it's still trying to use 4.0.1.45. You may need to close/reopen your terminal, or refresh your bash profile.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any reason for the problem. You can give a try this, Instead running the command from from within the sdk folder, run it from outside using this command: `sencha -sdk /path/to/sencha-touch-sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/www/myapp`

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the results of your suggestion