# Sencha generate app java error

Tags: java, sencha-touch-2, runtime-error

I am attempting to generate a sencha touch 2 app from within my touch-2.3.1 directory using the following command:

```
sencha generate app NewApp ../newapp
```

But I get the following error:

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67
[INF] 
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF] 
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] init-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF] 
[INF] init:
[INF] 
[INF] before-upgrade:
[INF] 
[INF] generate-app-impl:
[INF] 
[INF] generate-starter-app:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.2.67/sencha: line 58: 11092 Killed java $jvmArgs -jar "$BASEDIR"/sencha.jar "$@"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!

The answer to this problem was deceptively simple - update Java.

what happened was when I experienced my original problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371189/generating-sencha-touch-2-app-nullpointer-error/21645618#21645618), I had Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.4 installed. Uninstalling that and installing Sencha Cmd Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45 in a attempt to resolve the problem, I didn't realise my stable working environment was being compromised.

Anyway, when I resolved the problem linked above I was now running Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67 which I eventually realized was not compatible with `java version "1.6.0_27" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.10.4) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)`.

I updated by executing `apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin openjdk-7-jre` and my generate commands ran to completion.